# AWS RDS Database access from Github Actions

Tags: databases, aws, github, postgresql

I have a Postgres database hosted in AWS RDS. The rest of my application is also hosted on AWS.
The database migrations, like adding a new column, are done by [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/), a node package. The pipeline is on GitHub Actions.
There I run `npx prisma migrate deploy` script to modify the database on every deployment. To make it more secure, I created a random username, safe password, and port number different than the standard one.

How dangerous it is to make the database publicly accessible so that GitHub Actions can do the migrations on the database?

What other solution would you suggest to be able to run the migrations from the Github Actions?

Comment: have you considered a self-hosted runner in your environ? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#hardening-for-self-hosted-runners

Comment: Yeag, that is a good option. But if there is an easier but safe solution, I would still like to hear it

Comment: i'd be looking to restrict the ip addies that can access the rds instance (maybe using a security group/s), however, i read that [there are many github ip addies](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-githubs-ip-addresses) and they recommend checking the api weekly - from memory, you can have up to 32k rules in a security group - at the moment there are 3k action ip-cidr entries: too many to handle manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what the AWS support answered me, there are the following options to do that:

1. Alter the solution to make use of a bastion host that can receive connections from the internet and run the script from the bastion. You can use [this](https://github.com/moia-oss/bastion-host-forward) CDK library for that.
2. Use an EC2 instance as a self hosted GitHub Action runner
3. Allow connection to your instance over the public internet using the options available, due to dynamic IP this option would be difficult to achieve (not recommended)